# Can bullet point list rendering in MediaWiki be changed with add/insert feature for individual bullet point?

Tags: customization, mediawiki, bulletedlist

I am absolutely new to MediaWiki so I am afraid my question may seem very n00bish!

I am trying to make a community editable site where each topic page will contain only important points(as expandable points) instead of articles/paragraphs. Some of the points may have extra info like explanations, examples, pictures, etc (as nested bullets maybe?) which can be seen as tabs only if the point is expanded.

As a simple example, the page titled Lion won’t have any Infobox or paragraphs and will look like this:

```
 Lion
 ____________________________________________________________________

  +     Lions are carnivores
  +     Lions are highly social animals
  -     Adult male lions usually have manes
                     _______
                    |       |
         ___________|  Why  |_________
        | Something |       |   Pic   |
        |___________|       |_________|___________
        | The mane makes the lion look larger and |
        | protects his neck, throat and head.     |
        |_________________________________________|

  +     Lions hunt in coordinated groups
```

(Could not insert an image as I am a new user)

The whole page will be editable as usual but since the page will contain only points and sub-points I would like to have add/edit/insert/delete buttons for individual points. On clicking the add/insert/edit button a form will open in a modal window that will let the user add/edit the point and optionally the extra info.

So I think I need to make changes in the code that does parsing/rendering and also editing related changes. Also if nested-bullets cannot be used for tabs then maybe I need to introduce some new formatting rules.

My question is, is MediaWiki suited for this requirement?
Can all these/some be achieved through simple code changes without messing up the core?
If yes could you give me a few pointers on how to do them?
If not can you please suggest some alternative options?

Thanks

Comment: It should be possible to make sections look like bullet points. Could be done purely in JavaScript if you don't want to mess around with the renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the creation of editables points and sub-points : you could use titles to match your needs.
Main points will be Titles ( = Main point 1 = ), sub-points will be Sub-Titles ( == Sub point 2 == ).
This way, you will have an edit link at the right of each points and sub-points to only edit the point you want.
If you want to collapse/expand your points, I suggest you to take a look this documentation : [Collapsible elements](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCollapsible_elements). And a page with [live exemples](http://test.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aKrinkle/CollapsingTestpageMw).
And finally, if you want to create your own tags (to create you tabs for instance), take a look at this documentation : [Tag extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions).

Comment: Great. Thanks. I will try along the lines of your suggestion.